# Parsing nested XML into nested models with hasMany association in extJS4

Tags: xml, model, xml-parsing, extjs4, model-associations

I'm trying to parse a nested xml file into the models with hasMany association. I'm using ext JS 4.1.0. With extra tag, it works fine. But if I remove some tag, I doesn't work.

Here is my load_album.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <album id="3" name="Midnight Boom">
        <tracklist>
            <track id="5" name="Last Day of Magic" />
            <track id="12" name="Goodnight Bad Morning" />
        </tracklist>
    </album>
    <album id="4" name="Blood Pressures">
        <tracklist>
            <track id="1" name="Future Starts Slow" />
        </tracklist>
    </album>
</data>
```

Here is the models:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Album', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        mapping: '@id'
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: '@name'
    }],
    associations: [{
        type: 'hasMany',
        model: 'MyApp.model.Track',
        name: 'tracks',
        associationKey: 'tracklist',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'track',
            root: 'tracklist'
        }
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'xml/album_load.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'data',
            record: 'album'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Track', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        mapping: '@id'
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: '@name'
    }]
});
```

This is the store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Albums', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyApp.model.Album'
});
```

I list the data like this:

```
listdata: function() {
    var albumsstore = Ext.data.StoreManager.get("Albums");
    albumsstore.load(function(record, options, success) {
        if (success) {
            Ext.each(record, function(record) {
                console.log('Album: ' + record.data.name);
                var tracks = record.tracks();
                if (tracks.data.length > 0) {
                    Ext.each(tracks.data.items, function(tracks) {
                        console.log('Track: ' + tracks.data.name);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The result:

```
Album: Midnight Boom
Track: Last Day of Magic
Track: Goodnight Bad Morning
Album: Blood Pressures
Track: Future Starts Slow
```

It works fine.

My question is, how to parse the xml file into the model correctly if I remove the  tags like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <album id="3" name="Midnight Boom">
        <track id="5" name="Last Day of Magic" />
        <track id="12" name="Goodnight Bad Morning" />
    </album>
    <album id="4" name="Blood Pressures">
        <track id="1" name="Future Starts Slow" />
    </album>
</data>
```

It can read the album data but not the track data. Is this a limitation of extJS model? How to parse xml like this? Thanks.